# M:tG Unglued/Unhinged tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[A question about an Unhinged card](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28769/is-there-any-difference-between-double-strike-and-oubleday-ikestray) was posted today, and caused some confusion among voters.

I attempted to add an [mtg-unhinged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-unhinged) tag to make the joke more obvious, then I remembered that there's also Unglued so now I'm confused about how to name the tag.

1. Do we need a separate tag for these expansions?
2. If so, then what should it be?

EDIT: Not a lot of response, but no one was really against the tag so I went with [mtg-joke-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-joke-cards) and added it to a couple relevant questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think a tag is the right way to show this. Would someone ever want to look for all questions about Un-cards? It's possible, sure, but it doesn't seem like a common enough and useful enough scenario to warrant a tag. I think it'd be better for questions to manually note that any Un-cards they reference are such. It could be done with just a few words added.

That being said, this tag idea isn't really that bad. I'm not really *opposed* to the tag, it just doesn't seem necessary.

If the tag is to stick around, I suggest [mtg-un-sets](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-un-sets). Unglued and Unhinged and any future set of that nature are often called Un-sets.

An alternative, which would be more clear to those not familiar with the sets, would be [mtg-joke-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-joke-cards).

Comment: I agree with [mtg-joke-cards] because there are joke cards that are not in the Un-sets. If we're going to have a tag for this, we should include those too.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Which joke cards are you thinking of? Would that include the Christmas ones like Gifts Given?

Comment: Yes, the Happy Holidays cards are exactly what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with David Z (and a commenter on that answer) that [mtg-joke-cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-joke-cards) is an appropriate tag. Currently we have about five questions that could use the tag (four that mention Unhinged or Unglued by name, and this new one). A new tag would be useful for identifying duplicates, which is what I primarily use the search function for.

---

I'm one of the close voters, and I am not "confused" by the question. I understand that it's about a joke card. Serious questions about joke cards are totally fine.

I voted to close the question because I think the *question itself* is a joke.

A well written answer that mentioned both Pig Latin and Unhinged was posted first. Fifteen minutes later, a brief answer that mentioned neither of those things was posted and accepted within minutes. I posted a comment to that effect, and the OP immediately changed the accepted answer. Sounds fishy to me.

Comment: After reading your answer I removed part of my question. Sorry if I was accusive in any way, my focus point was the tag.

Comment: @freekvd I already moved the part about the tag to the top of the answer and separated it from my little rant with a horizontal bar. Your edited question, unfortunately, still accuses close voters of being confused. I would love to remove the second half of my answer altogether.

Comment: I do not see how an answer can be a valid close reason for a question.

Comment: @freekvd I can help you with that. Here's the text for the Primarily Opinion Based close reason: *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but **answers to this question** will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*

Comment: @freekvd And in case I totally misunderstood your comment, I never said, "An answer is a valid close reason for a question." I did say "The OP took actions that were suspect, and those actions involved an answer."

Comment: I considered myself a close voter, [I voted 'leave open'](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review/close/14886), and would argue that you and I have some confusion between us. I wasn't even aware who initiated the close vote so please don't take it personally.

Comment: @freekvd You voted 'leave open', and yet consider yourself a close voter?  I guess I have to agree with you. I *am* confused.